# Homework : Average of 10 user entered numbers

Tags: java, if-statement, average

I got this question and i tried several times and nothing comes to my mind :(

This is the question : Design and write a program to input 10 weights of people. It should only accept weights between the 20kg – 100kg. Your program should calculate and print the avg, max and min weights of these people.

This is the code i've tried. Can anyone complete this or come up with a simplified code ? Is this correct, i mean the way im doing this ? Please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class WeightOfPeople{
public static void main(String args []){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a weight between 20kg - 100kg :");
    int weight1 = sc.nextInt();


    if(20 < weight1 && weight1 < 100){
            System.out.print("Enter a weight between 20kg - 100kg :");
            int weight2 = sc.nextInt();             
    }else{
        System.out.println("Enter a correct weight");
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the user to be able to input *10 different values*. Therefore, you will need some sort of loop.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a weight: ");
    // record users input
}
```

What I would do is maintain an array of integers to store all of the data that the user enters. After you gather the data, you can loop over this array to determine the min, max and average. Something like this:

```
int min = weights[0];
int max = weights[0];
double avg = 0;

for (int weight : weights) {
    if (weight < min)
        min = weight;
    if (weight > max)
        max = weight;
    avg += weight;
}

avg /= weights.length;
```

---

Overall, you would have something like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] weights = new int[10];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a weight between 20 and 100: ");
    weights[i] = in.nextInt();
}
in.close();

int min = weights[0];
int max = weights[0];
double avg = 0;

for (int weight : weights) {
    if (weight < min)
        min = weight;
    if (weight > max)
        max = weight;
    avg += weight;
}

avg /= weights.length;

System.out.println("Min: " + min);
System.out.println("Max: " + max);
System.out.println("Average: " + avg);
```

Comment: Thanks friend :) can you write down the full answer here if you dont mind ?

Comment: @ŦhųLẩnåFệrñảnDö See the edit. But be careful when posting homework questions on StackOverflow, most users will not be this friendly if you ask them to do the homework for you...

Comment: @ A.R.S. - Thanks a lot friend... yeah im experiencing it right now :( 2 no research effort for this question :( thanks a lot again friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 0;
int total = 0;
int min = 101;
int max = 19;
while(count < 3) {
    System.out.print("Enter a weight between 20kg - 100kg :");
    int nextWeight = sc.nextInt();
    if(20 <= nextWeight && nextWeight <= 100){
        total += nextWeight;
        if(nextWeight < min) {
            min = nextWeight;
        }
        if(nextWeight > min) {
            max = nextWeight;
        }
        count++;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Enter a correct weight");
    }
}
System.out.println("Average = " + ((double)total/count));
System.out.println("Min = " + min);
System.out.println("Max = " + max);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args []){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
  do{
    System.out.print("Enter a weight between 20kg - 100kg :");
    int weight = sc.nextInt();
    if(20 <= weight && weight <= 100){
      sum += weight;
      if(weight<min){
        min = weight;
      }
      if(weight>max){
        max = weight;
      }
      i++;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Enter a correct weight");
    }
  } while(i<=10)
  System.out.println("AVG "+ (sum/10)+" Min "+ min +" Max "+max);
}
```